# How to stop Anaconda Navigator and Spyder from dropping libraries into User folder

Tags: python, directory, anaconda, spyder, libraries

For reference, I'm trying to re-learn programming and python basics after years away.

I recently downloaded Anaconda as part of an online Python Course. However, every time I open Spyder or the Navigator they instantly create folders for what I assume are all the relevant libraries in  C:Users/Myself. These include .conda, .anaconda, .ipython, .matplotlib, .config and .spyder-py3.

My goal is to figure out how change where these files are placed so I can clean things up and have more control. However, I am not entirely sure why this occurs. My assumption is it's due to that being the default location for the Working Directory, thought the solutions I've seen to that are currently above me. I'm hoping this is a separate issue with a simpler solution, and any light that can be shed on this would be appreciated.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no simple solution to this. So please leave those directories in their default locations.

Answer (score 0):

They are automatically created to store configuration changes for those related tools.  They are created in `%USERPROFILE%` under Windows.

### The following is NOT recommended:

You can change this either via the `setx` command or by opening the Start Menu search for `variables`.
- This opens the System Properties menu on the Advanced tab
- Click on Environmental Variables
- Under the user section, add a new variable called `USERPROFILE` and set the value to a location of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py

in def get_home_dir():

You can specify your preferred path directly.

Other anaconda applications can be mortified by this way but you have to find out in which scripts you can change the homedir, and sometimes it has different names.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps bringing this up from the dead, but you can do this on Windows using the mklink command to create a virtual link between folders.

So if you don't want C:\Users\YourName.application\garbage, but instead want C:\Application do the follwing. You will probably need administrator rights to do so.

```
mkdir C:\Application\Files
mklink /d C:\Users\YourName\.application C:\Application\Files
```

What this does is make it so the program is happy to think it's using C:\Users\YourName folders to do all its work, but for simplicity, the files are actually stored in a folder of your choice.