# How to *not* crowd your user folder with python/anaconda in Windows?

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-7

When I installed Python and Anaconda, it seems that the base path (I'm using Windows 7) is C:\Users\Erik. I ended up with a complete mess in my user folder. I moved the mess over to a folder (C:\Python) and reinstalled Anaconda (in the ProgramData folder, not the user folder) but I still get folders like ".conda", ".ipython", ".jupyter" and ".matplotlib" showing up in my user folder. I'm trying to avoid clogging the user folder, and would instead like all of that stuff to go to the C:\Python folder. I'm a noob to python (and any programming outside of MATLAB) so perhaps I don't know the relevant terminology to look this kind of thing up, but I've been trying to figure this out for a long time to no avail.

I was able to generate a configuration file for jupyter to have C:\Python be the default working directory, which is a start, but if I can keep my user directory clean that would be preferable (I'm guessing more and more configuration folders will be generated as I go along installing more packages and the like). Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: When installing Anaconda, you should be able to choose the installation location. See https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/.

Comment: The default installation path is somewhere in C:\ProgramData, but those configuration folders still end up in my user folder; I understand that I can choose the location, but if ProgramData redirects these config folders to my user folder, I don't see why choosing a different location would help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59929158/11301900

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on Windows using the mklink command to create a virtual link between folders.

So if you don't want C:\Users\Erik.conda, but instead want C:\Conda\files do the following. You will probably need administrator rights to do so.

```
mkdir C:\Conda\Files
mklink /d C:\Users\Erik\.conda C:\Conda\Files
```

What this does is make it so the program is happy to think it's using C:\Users\Erik folders to do all its work, but for simplicity, the files are actually stored in a folder of your choice.

I have this running on my computer so the user folder is only my files, while libraries and such are in a single global folder easily backed up. They should be system level files anyway and this greatly simplifies things.

Answer (score -1):

For myself personally I've found that using the virtual environments that are baked into python to be easier to maintain than using Anaconda. So one way to not crowd yourself with Anaconda is to not use it.

#### venv

The simple idea behind venv is that in a python project file you can create an folder which holds all of the python information and executables for that project. This means it will actually copy python's files from where it is installed in your system into that folder.

You can create a new python venv by executing:

`python -m venv .venv`

What this does is call the `venv` module (that is what the `-m` signifies) and effectively copies the content of your python install into a folder called `.venv`. The name `.venv` is not special in any way, it is just what the docs use and is fairly standard practice. Once this folder is created you can then activate the virtual environment by calling the `activate` script that is in the  `.venv/bin` folder. There are a couple of different "activate" scripts, which are for different systems (Windows vs. Unix ect...), but since you said you are a Windows user, you are interested in the powershell script (`activate.ps1`). Just run that script and you are in your venv, just like Anaconda.

Once activated you will see a `(.venv)` at the beginning of your console prompt. This now signifies that everything you do, will now be done to that venv. If install a package with `python -m pip install X` that package will be installed into the venv, and is now available to you every time you call `python` when the venv is active.

When you are done working in that venv you can just close your terminal/powershell window and the venv is deactivated. You can also type `deactivate` to get back to your normal environment.

#### Strategy

For me, I just install python on my system, and ONLY install packages into venvs. This can cause a bit of extra drive space being taken up, but that normally isn't an issue for most. The advantage to this is you never have to deal with the annoyance of WHERE things are being installed. Also, with the default name `.venv` the file is normally hidden from your file explorer, which keeps GUI's nice and clean.

So in your case, whenever you install `matplotlib` (or any other package for that matter), just make sure you are have activated the venv before you install it with `python -m pip install matplotlib`. Everytime you go back into your project and activate the venv, matplotlib will be there.

Hopefully that is helpful to you. Any other questions can probably be answered by the docs.

**venv documentation**: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: i see -- thanks very much for the advice, i will give this a shot